# C++ Insert Into Binary Search Tree Using Array

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, vector, binary-search-tree

So, within this particular program , I have nodes stored inside an vector of nodes. These nodes contain a user input int ID, int age, and string Name.

This vector is meant to act as a binary search tree that is organized by ID number, and is not worried about being balanced.

Currently I am attempting to write an insert function in which, after the creation of a new node of user input values, it compares it against the root, which is stored at index 1 of the vector.

If it is smaller than the ID at the root, then it is placed into position (root*2). If it is larger than the root, then it is placed into position (root*2 + 1)

However, I am having an extreme amount of difficulty placing into the vector if these two spots are already being taken up by another node.

Is there any way that I could create a loop that would check against the value in the filled spot, and continue looping until it finds an empty spot?

A current example that I'm working with

ID 50, ID 100, ID 75

ID 50 is in position 1.

ID 100 is inserted in position 3, since it is empty (2*1)

ID 75 is attempted to be inserted, but position 3 is filled, so then I need to check it against ID in position 3 using the same algorithm. In this case, since 75 is lower than 100, it would be placed in position 4.

I'm completely stumped as to how to to **implement such an algorithm into a loop**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code.

void BST::insert()
{

```
int ID;
int AGE;
string NAME;
bool done = false;

int root = 1;

cout << "Please enter the ID number, age and name" << endl;
do
{
    cin >> ID >> AGE >> NAME;
} while (ID <= 0);



Node *tree = new Node(ID, AGE, NAME);


if (!binaryTree.empty())
{

    do
    {
        Node &n = binaryTree.at(root);
        if (n.ID == 0)
        {
            n.ID = ID;
            n.age = AGE;
            n.name = NAME;
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (ID < n.ID)
        {
            root = 2 * root;
        }
        else
        {
            root = 2 * root + 1;
        }
    } while (done = true);
}

if (binaryTree.empty())
{
    binaryTree.push_back(*tree);
}


start();
```

}

I am still very new to this language, so any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

I fixed some discrepancies and added the code that was suggested, however, now an out_of_bounds exception is being thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: "*Is there any way that I could create a loop that would check against the value in the filled spot, and continue looping until it finds an empty spot?*" - yes, you should do exactly that. Can you specify where are you stuck? Did you use the debugger?

Comment: @Fureeish Basically I'm stuck at creating the algorithm to keep checking against the filled spot until it finds somewhere to place the newly created node.

Comment: lots of ways: [while loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while), [do while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do), [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), or even the good-ol [goto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto).  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @MFisherKDX My question is essentially, how would I turn such an alogrithm into a while loop/do while loop, etc.

Comment: @NomOnTheCookie unfortunately, it seems like you didn't even try to achieve what you want. We're not a code-writing service. Write out your pseudocode on a piece of paper and then try to implement what you came up with in your program. The moment you are stuck and able to specify what exactly is the issue is the moment you come here and explain

Comment: @Fureeish -- oh well, I just posted an answer 19 seconds after you suggested OP did not do enough work -- and you are probably right.  I do expect downvotes.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I think it's better for beginners to not know about `goto` since a lot of times you end up with spaghetti code.

Comment: Why are you implementing a binary tree with an array? You might as well just keep the array sorted due to the linear time insertion/removals.

Comment: @FeiXiang Binary heaps are [very naturally expressed as arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation). So it makes sense.  Regarding the goto, I respect your opinion.  However, I do think it's the easiest branching construct for beginners to understand.  I would actually probably implement with an empty for loop. `for(;;){ if(...){/*insert node*/ break; } root *= 2;  if (id > v[root].id) ++root; }`

Comment: @MFisherKDX I do know that binary heaps are implemented with arrays, but binary search trees are a different thing since you need to insert/remove from any location. BSTs also can have a variable number of nodes in each layer especially if you don't care about balancing, so an array would waste memory.

Comment: you are right about that ... missed the "Search Tree" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is essentially, how would I turn such an alogrithm into a
>   while loop/do while loop, etc

Here's an answer that uses pseudocode.  You should re-write the loop on your own with a different constuct such as a [while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while), [do while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) or [for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) loop.

But first, some problems with your code.

1. You are comparing `Node.ID` (an int) to `NULL` to check if a location in the vector is "empty".  `NULL` has the same semantics as `0` so I am going to assume that no IDs will be `0`.  Your code doesn't actually check this, so you may want to handle that case and/or address these design issues.
2. I have no idea why you are dynamically allocating memory with `new` if you are using a vector to store your nodes.  This is likely going to lead to a memory leak.
3. I am assuming you are handling creating a vector of the appropriate size in code you have not posted.  If you don't do this, then your code will crash when `at` throws an exception when `root` is outside the bounds of the vector.

> If it is smaller than the ID at the root, then it is placed into
>   position (root*2). If it is larger than the root, then it is placed
>   into position (root*2 + 1)

4. What if the ID is equal to the ID at the root?

And finally, the code with the goto loop.

```
int root = 1;

BEGIN LOOP            
    Node &n = binaryTree.at(root);
    if (n.ID == 0)
    {
        n.ID = ID;
        n.age = AGE;
        n.name = NAME;
        BREAK OUT OF LOOP
    }
    else if (ID < n.ID)
    {
        root = 2*root;
    }
    else
    {
        root = 2*root + 1;
    }
REPEAT
```

Comment: While I understand your reasoning, do understand that Cargo Cult programmers neither know nor care that `goto` is not the most straightforward solution to the problem. Rather than `goto` consider using a pseudocode.

Comment: @MFisherKDX So using this solution, would a do, while loop suffice to, whereas it continues to loop until binaryTree.size() changes?

Comment: No.  Where are you resizing the binaryTree vector?  If that is your intention, then your whole design is flawed.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Sorry. As said in the post, i'm extremely new to this language. Thank you for your answer. I am just now attempting to figure out how to actually begin the loop and repeat it until a parameter is met, I am just having difficulty deciding on that parameter.

Comment: I am sorry but your code is somewhat confusing and it makes me think you don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.  For instance, using your method, you must size your vector to "appropriately", initialize each ID with 0, and ensure that it does not grow beyond that. What is appropriate?  I don't know.  Instead of me leading you down the wrong path by making assumptions that may or may not apply, I suggest you ask your teacher or whoever gave you these requirements.  Because if this is homework, and you make the wrong design choice, it won't turn out well for you.  Good luck.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I edited the question for clarity. I hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170329/discussion-between-nom-onthecookie-and-mfisherkdx).